# Multiple image array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not too sure how to explain this, basically I want to make a array of images (hundreds of images) and then I would like a random 10 to be displayed on my website without any text. I'm not sure if it's possible to do this any other way.

```
function packOpen()
{
    var card = new Array();
    card[0] = "Messi";
    card[1] = "Ribery";
    card[2] = "Ronaldo";
    card[3] = "Neymar";
    card[4] = "Robben";
    card[5] = "Casillas";
}
```

I have tried making a array, but it doesn't display a result.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your array. Where is the problem occurring? Which line does it fail on? Try adding the minimum code that captures the failure to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of images really is in the hundreds you could use a PHP script to generate the array. It will scan a directory and find the images then generate a JavaScript array.

Save this as images.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/javascript");
//The directory of your images
$dir = "img";
echo "var images = [";
$arr = preg_grep("/[A-Za-z0-9].(jpg|gif|png|bmp|jpeg|svg)/",scandir($dir));
$index = 0;
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $index++;
    if($index < count($arr)) {
        echo "\"" . $dir . "/" . $value . "\", ";
    }
    else {
        echo "\"" . $dir . "/" . $value . "\"";
    }
}
echo "];";
?>
```

Then if you include it in the HTML file you can use the array variable images to access the array.

The in the JavaScript file (script.js):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("images");

    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = images[Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10)];
        div.appendChild(img);
    }
};
```

Finally the HTML file:

```
<script src="images.php"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```

If you simply want a function to return the adress of an img you could try:

```
function packOpen()
{
    var card = new Array();
    card[0] = "Messi";
    card[1] = "Ribery";
    card[2] = "Ronaldo";
    card[3] = "Neymar";
    card[4] = "Robben";
    card[5] = "Casillas";

    return card[Math.floor(Math.rand() * card.length)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is certanly looking fine to me. One approach to your problem could be to use the javascript functions "slice", "splice" and "sort".

```
function packOpen(numResults)
{
    var card = new Array();
    card[0] = "Messi";
    card[1] = "Ribery";
    card[2] = "Ronaldo";
    card[3] = "Neymar";
    card[4] = "Robben";
    card[5] = "Casillas";

    card.slice(0);
    card.sort( function() {
    return .5-Math.random();
    });

    return card.splice(0,numResults);
}

var randomItems = packOpen(10);
```